# Site Settings- Favicon configuration

Tags: sxa

I'm using sitecore 9.1 withSXA 1.8, i'm trying to add browser title and favicon to my site. I managed to add the browser title from SXA settings ( ../Settings/Browser) folder 
and then adding the metadata to my page designs Title however i can't find favicon in the settings folder. Is there another place where i configure my site favicon?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The favicon field is on the "Settings" item.

Some more detail:
When following the wizard to create a new tenant and site, the feature list shown as checkboxes determine which items are created and which base templates get inherited.

You may find that some field are missing from the Settings item if you did not check all features. You too can add your own tentant/site features to the wizard.

Comment: would you please tell me the path to this item? i checked the settings item in the path /sitecore/content/MySite/Portal/Settings but i can't find it there!

Comment: Ohhh sorry you're right, i missunderstood this, thought it was under the settings item, it's actually on it. Thank you so much